# Google charts javascript error

Tags: javascript, asp.net, json, google-visualization

I'm trying to display a google pie chart from data recovered from excel sheet.
The returned String is described below which I'm passing in `google.visualization.arrayToDataTable();`
The code that I have used is:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
  google.charts.load("current", {packages:["corechart"]});
  google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
   var str = '<%= JSNstring %>';     //returned string from C#.


  var res= str.replace(/""/g,"'");
  res=res.replace(/"/g,"'");
  // 
  var ss=[res];
  document.write(ss);    //the output of this is:
```

[['Solution','TOTAL'],['Check',23],['FULL',18],['POP',109]]

```
  function drawChart() {
    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(ss);

    var options = {
      title: 'My Daily Activities',
      pieHole: 0.4,
    };

    var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('donutchart'));
    chart.draw(data, options);
  }
</script>
```

This is showing error :
`JavaScript runtime error: First row is not an array.`

Please tell me what I'm doing wrong and how to correct it.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: can i have jsfiddle for this ?

Comment: @Sagar R you can see in my answer jsfiddle.

Comment: @thescion : no brother,its blank jsfiddle.

Comment: You are right- use this link https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/piechart#example

Comment: "code it yourself on jsfiddle link" button

Answer (score 0):

```
  `document.write(ss);`
```

Is only for this example, right? If it not so remove it and try to see inside your function what is the value of ss, like this-

```
function drawChart() {
console.write(ss);   
 var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(ss);

    var options = {
      title: 'My Daily Activities',
      pieHole: 0.4,
    };

    var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('donutchart'));
    chart.draw(data, options);
  }
```

**Update**

Try to rewrite your function drawChart() like this-

```
function drawChart() {
    var str = '<%= JSNstring %>';     //returned string from C#.


  var res= str.replace(/""/g,"'");
  res=res.replace(/"/g,"'");
  // 
  var ss=[res];
  var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(ss);

    var options = {
      title: 'My Daily Activities',
      pieHole: 0.4,
    };

    var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('donutchart'));
    chart.draw(data, options);
  }
```

**Update 2**

I created for you jsfiddle here [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2oqkwyt4/), with your array in hard code, as you can see it is working here.So your problem is something with the server side or with the value of ss.

Comment: Yes I did but the program is breaking at the start page onlyand the error is coming.
`JavaScript runtime error: First row is not an array.`

Comment: You have to open the console and see what is written about ss value.

Comment: I used console but it's showing error and breaking.
`JavaScript runtime error: Object doesn't support property or method 'write'`

Comment: still same error is coming.
`. JavaScript runtime error: First row is not an array.`

Comment: Where is your div of 'donutchart'?

Comment: in this code 'var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('donutchart'));' you are using div with id of donutchart, where is this div?

Comment: Yes I have a div of donut chart in my code.
also  the hard code part -  I have also tried it the same way and it's working but it depends on selected variable which is fetching data and returning the required `JSNstring`
so this is just 1 example or output .(1 of value)

Comment: Add your c# code and try to replace var ss=[res]; with var ss= res.split(',');

Comment: There was a browser problem,it was not supporting JSON.
Now code works fine after adding JSON support.

**Thanks Buddy for help**

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to *parse* the string into an array, try this...

```
google.charts.load("current", {packages:["corechart"]});
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
 var str = '<%= JSNstring %>';     //returned string from C#.


var res= str.replace(/""/g,"'");
res=res.replace(/"/g,"'");
var ss='[' + res + ']';

function drawChart() {
  var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(eval(ss));

  var options = {
    title: 'My Daily Activities',
    pieHole: 0.4,
  };

  var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('donutchart'));
  chart.draw(data, options);
}
```